# How to cancel performBlock:

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperationqueue

I implemented a search and for every new character typed by the user a `performFetch:` is started inside of a `performBlock:`. If the search string changes I would like to cancel the previous started block and start over. How would I cancel or at least inform the block inside the `performBlock:`about it?

Example code I have right now:

```
[myManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        // fetch from background queue
        if([[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:nil]) {
            // update the view from the main queue
            // don't do this if performBlock already got started again! but how?
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                // refresh UI
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to cancel a `performBlock`. Once it starts, it continues until it completes or until your code `return`s from it.

If you find it necessary to cancel fetches while they are in progress, look into `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`, which allows cancellation via `NSProgress`. Async fetch requests and cancellation are described in the [WWDC 2014 Core Data session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/225/)

Comment: Thanks for this clear and simple answer. `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`looks like a good solution